# UITableViewCell not visible in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView on the ViewController. Here is complete code

```
import UIKit

class UnitTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var unitTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.unitTable.register(UnitCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UnitCell")
        self.unitTable.delegate = self
        self.unitTable.dataSource = self

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = unitTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UnitCell", for: indexPath) as! UnitCell
        cell.unitNameLbl?.text = "TEST"

        return cell
    }

}
```

But unfortunately my custom cell is not visible. I've put green background colour to be sure that constraints are right. 
Here is my UnitCell code

```
import UIKit

class UnitCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var unitNameLbl: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet weak var unitNumberLbl: UILabel?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

What could be wrong if I can't see my custom cell?

Comment: Have you set estimatedHeight and/or height for row ? Else I believe it defaults to 44pts.

Comment: check the reuseIdentifier of cell. if it is given properly or not. and try  
 unitTable.register(UINib(nibName: "yourIdentifier", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:  "yourIdentifier") .  to register a nib

Comment: have a look at the outlet of the tableview. if it is connected or not.

Comment: Can you please provide for cell if available.

Comment: @GoodSp33d I've made it bigger, didn't help.

Comment: Perhaps you have dequeued it as a class, instead of Nib. As Arpita mentioned try registering it as a Nib

Comment: @PranjalBikashDas tableView is connected properly with outlet

Comment: @Micgal no need to register cell in viewDidLoad() if you are using storyboard, just remove that line.

Comment: @arpita that's correct! 
I've just put 
 unitTable.register(UINib(nibName: "UnitCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UnitCell") and working as expected.
And also removed self.unitTable.register(UnitCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UnitCell")

Comment: yes. because of you have dequeued it in class, instead of Nib. you should register it as a Nib. @Micgal

Comment: @arpita so if I create cell in custom Nib (It's the same as xib?) then I've to register Nib, but if I create cell in my Main storyboard, directly on TableView I do not have to register as Nib? Am I right?

Comment: yes exactly @Micgal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this following into viewDidLoad

```
unitTable.register(UINib(nibName: "yourCellClassName", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UnitCell")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly use class name of cell because you'r using XIB of cell so you must need to register cell with nib name like below.

```
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "YourTableViewCellNibName", bundle: nil)
    self.unitTable.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "UnitCell")
```

Answer (score 0):

change registering cell to table code as below.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.unitTable.register(UINib(nibName: "UnitTable", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "UnitCell") // nibName should be exact name of xib file of your custom cell.
        self.unitTable.delegate = self
        self.unitTable.dataSource = self

    }
```